# Adding media queries in SASS file

Tags: sass, media-queries

I've been using Bootstrap and SASS together for the first time in my new project.

I've just added the following lines in my SASS file and compiled with [Prespos](https://prepros.io/),

```
@media (min-width: $screen-sm-min){
#myemail
  padding-top: 20px
}
```

Surprisingly, it showed the following error,

> Failed to compile style.sass | Error: Invalid CSS after "}": expected 1 selector or at-rule, was "{}"
>
> 13 |         padding-top: 20px
>
> 14 |     }

I've tried several workarounds and luckily got that compile successfully with the following code with a very minor change ( **just moved the closing brace to previous line** ),

```
@media (min-width: $screen-sm-min){
#myemail
  padding-top: 20px}
```

I wonder is that the way SASS work. Can you explain the specific reason behind this behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

You forget braces around `#myemail` selector.

```
@media (min-width: $screen-sm-min) {
  #myemail {
    padding-top: 20px;
  }
}
```

There are may be some expressions under one media query:

```
@media (min-width: $screen-sm-min) {
  .one {
    ...
  }

  .two {
    ...
  }

  .three {
    ...
  }
}
```

What's more you can white media query inside rule:

```
#myemail {
  padding-top: ...

  @media (min-width: $screen-sm-min) {
    padding-top: 20px;
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do we need braces while using **SASS** and not **SCSS** as [here](http://sass-lang.com/guide) ?

Comment: @SathyamoorthyR on sass remove braces around #myemail :) Like here http://www.sassmeister.com/gist/57f91b899cf7fa769b3e6abb9da7d81b